# Angular `watch` does not behave as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following snippet of code

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $log){

  $scope.name = 'guy';
  $scope.guy = {};


  function myWatch(){
    return function(newValue, oldValue){
      $log.info('these are the values',newValue, oldValue);

      if ( newValue === oldValue ){
        $log.info('they are the same');
      }
    }
  }

  $scope.$watch('guy',myWatch(), true);

  $scope.guy = { 'hello' : 'world' };

}
```

which you can [run on plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BuAr9VZGi86jFkNlkarN?p=preview) - **look for console prints!**

The idea is :

- assign a value to scope property `guy`
- set a `$watch` on that property
- assign another value to `guy`
- expect `newValue` and `oldValue` to be different and to NOT see `they are the same` print in the console log - **fails**

  - more specifically I expect `oldValue` to be `{}` and newValue to be `{ 'hello':'world' }`

What am I doing wrong, and how should I implement this logic when required?

Comment: What you are seeing is an expected behavior. You are changing the value of `guy` twice before the next digest cycle (due to controller initialization) happens. So initial watch run will show both of them the same. Now look at your console.. http://plnkr.co/edit/pAND9x?p=preview in this example. When we delay the change in the property value to the next digest cycle, you will what you were originally expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are experiencing an issue with timing, the watch is not completely set up before the value changes and when a digest is finally run the values are indeed the same if you do this:

```
$timeout(function(){
   $scope.guy = { 'hello' : 'world' };
},3000,true);
```

this will give you enough time to have the watch setup and also see a change at a later point. With this change your expectation should be meet.

**Edit To Further explain $watch and digest cycles:**

`$watch` is called on every `$digest cycle` regardless if the value being watched is changed or not, however, the `listener` is only called on the first `$digest` cycle, but not called until the watched value changes. In addition the watch can run multiple times in each `$digest` cycle, thus the `listener` might be called several times in the first cycle.

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Here is a code snippet:

```js
function MyCtrl($scope, $log, $timeout) {

  $scope.name = 'guy';
  $scope.guy = {};


  function myWatch() {
    return function(newValue, oldValue) {
      $log.info('these are the values', newValue, oldValue);

      if (newValue === oldValue) {
        $log.info('they are the same');
      } else {
        $log.info('they are different');
      }
    }
  }

  $scope.$watch('guy', myWatch(), true);

  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.guy = {
      'hello': 'world'
    };
  }, 3000, true);


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.16" data-semver="1.2.16" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain than why `watch` is fired at all? if both values are the same?

Answer (score 3):

There is no additional change to watch as the watch is evaluated as part of the digest cycle. I created a sample that changes `guy` in a function, called from a button click.

I also tweaked your watch function to just be the function rather than a function that returns a function.

```
function myWatch(newValue, oldValue){
  $log.info('these are the values',newValue, oldValue);

  if ( newValue === oldValue ){
    $log.info('they are the same');
  }    
}
```

$scope.$watch('guy',myWatch, true);

http://plnkr.co/edit/qCyvyLyNDscdFcQ3rsUj?p=preview